# Add data manually to gridcontrol devexpress C#

Tags: c#, devexpress

I got into trouble with adding data to devexpress grid programmably. I parse data from the site with HTML Agility Pack and want to add parsed data to grid. I create 13 columns in gridcontrol with wizard.

```
    private void buttonGetData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string url = @"____";
        HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
        HtmlDocument document = web.Load(url);
        var node = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr[not(@class)]/td[@style='width:1%;' or @class='coef' or (@class='left' and .//a)]");

        /*foreach (var innerText in node.Select(row => row.InnerText))
        {
            gridView1.AddNewRow();
            gridView1.SetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, gridView1.Columns["colunmDate"] , innerText);
            gridView1.UpdateCurrentRow();
        }*/
    }
```

I get about 2000 elements into node. In this code i get InnerText from Node. Commented code doesn't work (and it's just for test). Please, help me with adding data to DevExpress Grid. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that *document* variable is well formed Xml you can load this into DataSet instance as

```
XmlTextReader MyReader = new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(Buffer));
MyDataSet.ReadXml(MyReader, XmlReadMode.Auto);
```

Then you may attach appropriate table as *GridView1.DataSource* directly or transform it before attaching.

Comment: I tried with BindingList but there's no effect too (( 
` public Coeff(string date, string time, string teams)
            {
                this.date = date;
                this.time = time;
                this.teams = teams;
            }`

Comment: `           BindingList<Coeff> coeffs = new BindingList<Coeff>();
            foreach (var innerText in node.Select(row => row.InnerText))
            {
                coeffs.Add(new Coeff(innerText, innerText, innerText));
            }

            gridControl1.DataSource = coeffs;
            gridControl1.RefreshDataSource();
        }`